# How to use "come from" (order of come and from)?

Tags: american-english, adverbs

I'm not sure about the order used for "come" and "from". Is this correct?

> He is leaving the house, back to *the garden where he comes **from***.

If the flavor is meaningful, I'm using the sentence for American-English.

Comment: to "come from" in "where he comes from" means either that he grew up there, or that the place is where he has a home and lives. Is that what you mean to say?

Comment: Also, we cannot "leave ...back".    We can leave, and **go** back.  *He is leaving the house, **going** back to the garden he comes from.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: That's exactly what I meant, but I used an ellipsis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where he comes from

is the correct ordering to say his *place of origin*, you could also say

> from where he came